# Focus angular material input on clicking tilde

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6

I have an angular material input in a component "**awesomebar.component.html**"  like:

```
<input #placeAutocompleteInput style="max-width:100%;" 
       [placeholder]="placeholderText"
       [matChipInputFor]="chipListPlaces" 
       [formControl]="mainSearchCtrl" 
       [matAutocomplete]="mainAutocomplete" 
       (keyup.enter)="onEnter($event)"/>
```

I am defining an angular directive to highlight the input element when I click tilde(~) in another file **keyboard.directive.ts**. When I click the (~) from the keyboard, the input element should get highlighted.

My code for directives :

```
@HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event']) onKeydownHandler(event: KeyboardEvent) {
        if(event.keyCode === 192) 
         {
               // input focus logic
               this.placeAutocompleteInput.nativeElement.focus();
               this.placeAutocompleteInput.nativeElement.value = '';
         } 
    }
```

I can't get the placeAutocompleteInput.nativeElement in the above logic. How can I make it work . Since the input element is in another component file and directive is defined in different file, I can't able to access the nativeElement.

**Edit:** **got the answer with following adjustments** :

In  file awesomebar.component.html:

```
<input #placeAutocompleteInput style="max-width:100%;" 
                [placeholder]="placeholderText"
                [matChipInputFor]="chipListPlaces" 
                [formControl]="mainSearchCtrl" 
                [matAutocomplete]="mainAutocomplete" 
                (keyup.enter)="onEnter($event)"
                captureDoubleTilde/>
```

In file keyboard.directive.ts :

```
@Directive({
      selector: `[captureDoubleTilde]`
    })
    export class CaptureDoubleTildeDirective {
      constructor(
        public dialog: MatDialog,
        private el: ElementRef
        ) { }

        @HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event']) onKeydownHandler(event: KeyboardEvent) {
             if(event.keyCode === TILDE_KEYCODE && localStorage.accessToken != undefined) {
                pressCount += 1;
                var focus= 0;
                if (pressCount >1) {
                    var scrollStep = -window.scrollY / (50 / 15),
                    scrollInterval = setInterval(function(){
                        if ( window.scrollY != 0 ) {
                            window.scrollBy( 0, scrollStep );

                        }
                        else clearInterval(scrollInterval); 
                    },15);
                    this.el.nativeElement.focus();
                    this.el.nativeElement.value = '';

                }
                setTimeout(() => pressCount=0, 200);

            }
        }



    }
```

however when I am double clicking the tilde, along with highlight, (~) character is showing in my input, how can i correct it.

Comment: Why you're using @Hotlistener about 'document:keyDown' and not about 'keyDown? can you use event.target.focus()?

Comment: @Eliseo how can i bind the input to the hostListener event? Is there any way?

Comment: Use a clasic directive, https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#build-a-simple-attribute-directive (int constructor you have constructor(private el: ElementRef), use this "el" to make the focus

Comment: @Eliseo, i made it work with your tips, but a character (~) is appearing in the input how can i correct it. check the update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I edited the [**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9xnyms?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). All is applied to the same level component and directive, but you can split those and use in higher level, but also add **TestService** to app.module providers array and import it.

---

What is `this.placeAutocompleteInput`? Is that snippet from your directive? If it is and if you applied it to your input, you should make it work by accessing directive's host via **ElementRef**:

```
import {ElementREf} ...

constructor(private elR: ElementRef){}

@HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event']) onKeydownHandler(event: KeyboardEvent) {
        if(event.keyCode === 192) 
         {
               // input focus logic
               this.elR.nativeElement.focus();
               this.elR.nativeElement.value = '';
         } 
    }
```

p.s. I also wonder why you need to `focus()` if key pressed - isn't it focused already?

Here you can [see a DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zbsqxo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). I changed couple events, but the idea is the same. Click `space` and focus will be removed and input's value also empty string.

Comment: the key press don't automatically focus the input. The key can be pressed at anywhere in the page. I need to capture the hotkey (~). If its pressed than the input gets highlighted

Comment: So you should apply this directive to the top level element, like`<body>` and when button pressed, emit en event (probably service is a best choice). That component where button sits watch for that event and do `focus()` when it happens

Comment: Me too :) updated. Press space and input gets focused

Comment: however m facing a different problem with this solution, check my update

Comment: if your problem that after clicking second time you also get the character, you could add a boolean value in same directive - `clicked = false`. When that keypress happens, change it to true and second time if it pressed and if that boolean is true use `event.preventDefault()`